# What does `RAWINPUT::header::wParam` contain for keyboard input

Tags: c++, winapi, raw-input

On looking at the MSDN documentation for `RAWINPUT` structure, it has the following declaration:

```
typedef struct tagRAWINPUT {
  RAWINPUTHEADER header;
  union {
    RAWMOUSE    mouse;
    RAWKEYBOARD keyboard;
    RAWHID      hid;
  } data;
} RAWINPUT, *PRAWINPUT, *LPRAWINPUT;
```

Further, the `RAWINPUTHEADER` struct contains these:

```
typedef struct tagRAWINPUTHEADER {
  DWORD  dwType;
  DWORD  dwSize;
  HANDLE hDevice;
  WPARAM wParam;
} RAWINPUTHEADER, *PRAWINPUTHEADER;
```

Of which the thing of interest is the member `wParam`:

> wParam
>
> Type: WPARAM
>
> The value passed in the wParam parameter of the WM_INPUT message.

So, what exactly does this wParam contain? (specifically for keyboard KEYDOWN input?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for [`WM_INPUT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645590.aspx) tells you this information:

> *wParam*
>  
>   The input code. This parameter can be one of the following values.
>
> **RIM_INPUT**
>   0
>  
>   Input occurred while the application was in the foreground. The application must call DefWindowProc so the system can perform cleanup.
>
> **RIM_INPUTSINK**
>   1
>  
>   Input occurred while the application was not in the foreground. The application must call DefWindowProc so the system can perform the cleanup.